# Is there an analytics tool for webOS apps?

Tags: analytics, webos, palm

I need to track individual page views on my webOS app, something akin to Google Analytics. I understand that tracking on web apps may be barebones, but anything is better than nothing. Does anyone know of an analytics tool for webOS, or one that is compatible?

The nice to haves are: support for offline mode, minimal use of bandwidth, and custom variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no clean set of tools for what you want. However, [logging](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1565) and [framework_config.json](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1725) combined allow you to at least gather your data. I'm sure you could add something to allow your clients to upload this usage data. You probably should not do this without their consent though.

In addition, there might be some low level system you could hook into. You may have seen [this article](http://kitenet.net/~joey/blog/entry/Palm_Pre_privacy/) about the data the palm pre sends home (to palm) on a regular basis. However, AFAIK there are no public hooks for this functionality, so some digging is needed to use it (if that is at all possible).

Answer (score 2):

Try Metrix from webosroundup.com

http://metrix.webosroundup.com/